# display label with UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator

Tags: iphone

I hope display label as below

[image]

So I used the codes below to display label with UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator

```
cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero//  cellframe //SimpleTableIdentifier1
                             reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier1] autorelease];

cell.accessoryType=  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;// 
UILabel *labelCell =[ [[UILabel alloc]init] autorelease];
[labelCell setTag:11101];
labelCell.frame = CGRectMake(180.9f,15.0f,60.0f,23.0f) ;
[labelCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
labelCell.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
[labelCell setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];
[labelCell setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[cell.contentView addSubview:labelCell];
```

UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator will display correctly
but the labelCell does not display, except I tap the row of the UITasbleViewCell

[image]

Welcome any comment

Comment: Are you saying it is 10 & 15 but appears as 10 & 5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the frame property of your `UILabel`,
try with changing value for **x** and **y**.

```
labelCell.frame = CGRectMake(180.9f,15.0f,60.0f,23.0f) ;
```

You could also consider to implement the accessory using `accessoryView`.

[Implement a Custom Accessory View For UITableView in iPhone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I think doing this,

```
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:labelCell];
```

will help but since there are other subviews in the table cell you will have to deal with their layout as well. Rather I suggest you create a new custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: @monsabre Is this problem still persistent?